# $postLink of an angular component/directive running too early

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Update:** I put a bounty on this question. I am not looking for hacks or workarounds. I am looking for an official way to access the dom in an angular component, and an explanation why the behavior I see ($postLink running to early) seems to be contradictory to the official docs.
The official docs state ([here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)):

> $postLink() - Called after this controller's element and its children have been linked. Similar to the post-link function this hook can be used to set up DOM event handlers and do direct DOM manipulation

**Original question:** I have an example of the problem here -> http://plnkr.co/edit/rMm9FOwImFRziNG4o0sg?p=preview

I am using an angular component and I want to modify the dom in the post link function, but it doesn't work, it seems that the function runs too early, before the template is actually ready in the dom after all the angular processing.

In the html page, I have this:

```
<my-grid grid-id="'foo'"></my-grid>
```

The component is defined as:

```
appModule.component('myGrid',{
    controller: gridController,
    bindings: {
        "gridId": "<",
    },
    templateUrl: 'gridTemplate'
});
```

In the component template I have this:

```
<table id='{{$ctrl.gridId}}'>
...
```

(The binding itself works, there is no doubt. Eventually, in the html the id of the table is 'foo' as expected).

In the controller, I have something like this:

```
function gridController($scope, $compile, $attrs) {
    console.log ("grid id is: " + this.gridId); // 'foo'

    this.$postLink = function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById(this.gridId);
        // do something with elem, but elem is null
    }
}
```

What I see when debugging is that when the $postLink function is executed, the table is in the dom but its id attribute is still `{{$ctrl.gridId}}` instead of `foo`, so `document.getElementById()` finds nothing. This seems in contrast to the documentation.
What am I missing? Is there a different way to access the dom in the component?

**Update 2:** Today I realized the same problem occurs with the regular link function of directives, it is not limited to components. So apparently I misunderstood the meaning of "do direct DOM manipulation" - the link function runs on an element that is detached from the dom, so using the `document` object with selectors is useless.

Comment: [link timming](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2603-directive-controller-and-link-timing-in-angularjs.htm) hope it help

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The documentation regarding `$postLink()` is correct. It's called after its controller's element and its children have been linked. This doesn't mean that you'll see a directive's result immediately. Maybe it's calling `$http` and inserting the result once it arrives. Maybe it's registering a watcher which in turns sets the result, *as most of Angular's built-in directives do*.

The underlying issue in your case is that you want to perform DOM manipulations after **the interpolations have been compiled**, or better yet, after their registered watcher had had time to run once.

Unfortunately, there isn't *an official way* to do this. Nevertheless, there are ways of accomplishing this, but you won't find them listed in the documentation.

Two popular ways of **running a function after the interpolations have been compiled** are:

- using `$timeout` without a delay (as it defaults to 0): `$timeout(function() { /* Your code goes here */ });`
- using `.ready()` which is provided by [Angular's jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

In your case, you're much better off using a watcher to run a function once the element with the given ID exists:

```
var deregistrationFn = $scope.$watch(() => {
    return document.getElementById(this.gridId);
}, (newValue) => {
    if (newValue !== null) {
        deregistrationFn();

        // Your code goes here
    }
});
```

Finally, in my opinion, I believe that whenever you need to wait for the interpolations to be compiled, or for certain directives to insert their value, you're not following *the Angular's way of building things*. In your case, why not create a new component, `myGridTable` which requires `myGrid` as a parent, and add its appropriate logic there. This way, each component's responsibility is much better defined and it's easier to test things.

Comment: This is the correct answer so I granted the bounty. After my own investigation I more or less knew the details, but this answer explains it in clearer terms. Also, the use of $watch with a function instead of a timeout is a very nice addition :)  I will try to implement it also with a sub-component, see if that works ...

Comment: It's been a while, but would you mind giving more details, external links or an example of the Angualr's way you mentioned, to avoid using $timeout? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 14):

The misunderstanding is in how the angular $digest cycle works in conjunction with the controller life cycle events (and directive life cycle events).

Each of the controller/directive life cycle events are called inside of an $apply. Because of this, the DOM is only updated to reflect changes after the [$digest cycle is completed](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop).

The post link function runs after everything has been linked, but it is [at the end of this function](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/28/compile-pre-and-post-linking-in-angularjs.aspx) that DOM is updated to reflect any bindings, due to it being the last function run inside of the $digest cycle. This means that trying to query the DOM for anything affected by a binding will not work (such as an `ng-repeat`, or in you're case, a bound value). But as the docs state, the linking of the DOM has already been run, so the initial template has been created and is able to be manipulated.

Since you need to query the DOM after bindings have been applied, you need to run you're code after the current $digest cycle has been completed. This means using a `$timeout` with a delay of 0, which will be [executed right after the current $digest cycle has ended](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/run-a-directive-after-the-dom-has-finished-rendering/).

```
function gridController($scope, $compile, $attrs, $timeout) {
    console.log ("grid id is: " + this.gridId); // 'foo'

    this.$postLink = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            var elem = document.getElementById(this.gridId);
            // do something with elem now that the DOM has had it's bindings applied
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for make it clear, i was searching for such right hints.

Answer (score 2):

Its seems relevant to understanding of a angular component scenarios before giving any solution.  And what i see from your example the template DOM loaded in an **isolated** scope. Repeat an **isolated** scope

So,

> According to the official doc [1.5.6] on components https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

**When not to use Components:**

- **for directives that rely on DOM manipulation, adding event listeners etc,** **because the compile and link functions are unavailable**
- when you need advanced directive definition options like priority, terminal, multi-element
- when you want a directive that is triggered by an attribute or CSS class, rather than an element

> If you review the section "Comparison between Directive definition and Component definition" from the doc, you'll see

- **feature------------directive-----------component**
- bindings------------No-------------------Yes (binds to controller)
- bindToController----Yes (default: false)-No (use bindings instead)
- compile function----Yes------------------No
- controller----------Yes------------------Yes (default function() {})
- controllerAs--------Yes------------------(default: false) Yes (default: $ctrl)
- link functions------Yes------------------No

Now

> Components should never modify any data or DOM that is out of their
>   own **scope**. Normally, in Angular it is possible to modify data anywhere
>   in the application through **scope** inheritance and watches. This is
>   practical, but can also lead to problems when it is not clear which
>   part of the application is responsible for modifying the data. That is
>   why component directives use an **isolate** scope, so a whole class of
>   scope manipulation is not possible.  **REF**: *ng-doc 1.5.6*

But when you see, There is ad $postLink() hook available, you might wondering what's the reason for?

However, if you go through the description of this hook you'll find ...

> **Note** that child elements that contain **templateUrl** directives will not have been **compiled** and **linked** since they are waiting for their template to load asynchronously and their own compilation and linking has been suspended until that occurs.

Please refer to the Steven Lambert answers below ...

Comment: About the last comment, I thought that by child elements they mean other angular directives inside the current component. In my template currently there is only basic html. If the templateUrl was not compiled and linked, why do they call that callback function $postLink?

Comment: Im also exploring and found 2 possible workaround , 1 is to use $compileProvider service and another is compile the templateUrl in postlink and assign to a property into component. you can also try this way or any other perspective. Hope will come with a solution soon

Comment: I changed it to template instead of templateUrl and it still doesn't work. The note about the URLs loaded asynchronously is not related to this problem, it refers to child directives only

Comment: did you review the section Intercomponent Communication from the doc? Im in office now, i'll do some more RND when back home.

Comment: I also look for the answer, this makes me crzzy. also this can be a workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745155/angularjs-make-isolate-scope-directive-template-bind-to-parent-scope

Comment: "for directives that rely on DOM manipulation, adding event listeners etc, because the compile and link functions are unavailable" this wording has been removed from the officially docs.